# Python: FileNotFoundError not caught by try-except block

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, file-not-found

recently i started learning Python and encountered a problem i can`t find an answer to.
Idea of the program is to ask for username, load a dictionary from JSON file, and if the name is in the dictionary - print the users favourite number.

The code, that loads the JSON file looks like this:

```
import json

fav_numbers = {}
filename = 'numbers.JSON'

name = input('Hi, what`s your name? ')
try:
    with open(filename) as f_obj:
        fav_numbers = json.load(f_obj)
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass

if name in fav_numbers.keys():    

    print('Hi {}, your fav number is {}, right?'.format(name, fav_numbers[name]))

else:
    number = input('Hi {}, what`s your favourte number? '.format(name))
    fav_numbers[name] = number

    with open(filename, 'w') as f_obj:
        json.dump(fav_numbers, filename)
```

Still, as i try to run it, it crashes, telling me:

```
Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'numbers.JSON'
  File "/home/niedzwiedx/Dokumenty/Python/ulubionejson.py", line 22, in <module>
    with open(filename) as f_obj:
```

What i`m doing wrong to catch the exception? (Already tried changing the FileNotFoundError to OSError or IOError)

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Is this really all your code?

Comment: The error probably comes from somewhere else in your code. Can you provide more code and the full traceback for the error ?

Comment: actually this is not enough information

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. I added full code and error message.

Comment: Your edited code should not match the error provided. If the file does not exists, it should fail on line 13 with a ``KeyError`` when accessing ``if fav_numbers[name]: `` As for your edited question: line 22 is not wrapped in a ``try..except`` block, only the lines 8 and 9 are.

Comment: Thanks. I edited it and it should work now.

Comment: Your traceback still does not match the code you provide : 
`with open(filename) as f_obj:` in you traceback is actually 
`with open(filename, 'w') as f_obj:` in your code. Are you sure that you run the same file that you are editing ?

Answer (score 2):

The error comes from you last line, outside of your try/except

```py
with open(filename, 'w') as f_obj:
        json.dump(fav_numbers, filename)
```

filename is a string, not a file.

You have to use

```py
with open(filename, 'w') as f_obj:
        json.dump(fav_numbers, f_obj)
```

For additional safety, you can surround this part with  try/except too

```py
try:
    with open(filename, 'w') as f_obj:
        json.dump(fav_numbers, f_obj)
except (FileNotFoundError, PremissionError):
    print("Impossible to create JSON file to save data")
```

---